# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in UITableView

Tags: swift3

While I am setting up a model for my chat screen info. I am getting the below error on this line

```
cell.chatViewLabel.text = chat.chatText
```

*fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

Here is the code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "ChatTableViewCell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ChatTableViewCell  else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of ChatTableViewCell.")
    }

    // Fetches the appropriate chat for the data source layout.
    let chat = chats[indexPath.row]
    cell.chatViewLabel.text = chat.chatText

    return cell
}
```

I am new in swift and any prompt help would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Has chatViewLabel been setup at this point. Maybe if you post the code for your ChatTableViewCell someone can help

Comment: so ChatTableViewCell has an outlet label connect to story board prototype cell. No code inside as of now

Comment: Hmmm, must say I've not used story board to associate prototype cells with classes so can't say when outlets are setup. Have you checked if chatViewLabel is nil?

Comment: No I didn't check earlier, but Yes its nil. I think I got the point. Thanks

Comment: My bad, I have a duplicate custom cell created and instead of linking outlets to prototype cell I am setting outlet to that custom cell xib. Appreciate your help.